# Question on the definition of the direct sum of $C^*$ algebras: Why $c_0$-sum and not $l^\infty$-sum?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, direct-sum

Let $(\mathfrak{A}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of $C^*$-algebras. Let $\|\cdot\|_n$ denote the norm of $\mathfrak{A}_n$.Then its infinite direct sum is defined as the $c_0$-direct sum (cp. [1](http://www.math.uvic.ca/faculty/putnam/ln/C*-algebras.pdf))
\begin{equation}
\bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathfrak{A}_n = \left\{(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \middle | A_n \in \mathfrak{A}_n \mathrm{~and~} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \|A_n\|_n = 0\right\}
\end{equation}
together with the sup-norm $\| (A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|_\infty = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|A_n\|_n$ and componentwise defined multiplication/summation/involution?

My question is: Why isn't it defined as the $l^\infty$-direct sum given by

\begin{equation}
\infty-\bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathfrak{A}_n = \left\{(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \middle | A_n \in \mathfrak{A}_n \mathrm{~and~} \| (A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\|_\infty < \infty\right\}
\end{equation}
together with the sup-norm and multiplication/summation/involution defined componentwise.

Sources:

[1](http://www.math.uvic.ca/faculty/putnam/ln/C*-algebras.pdf): Example 1.2.5 of ["Lecture notes on C^*-algebras" by Ian F. Putnam](http://www.math.uvic.ca/faculty/putnam/ln/C*-algebras.pdf)

Comment: If you say "direct sum" you want the category's co-product. The "$\ell^\infty$-sum" you have written down will probably be the product of the category of $C^*$-algebras. These two things have explicit definitions and it can be checked which "sum" corresponds to which definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)

Comment: Upon further reflection, the product is indeed what you call the $\ell^\infty$ sum, but I do not believe there is a $C^*$ co-product over infinite index sets.  Still the $c_0$ sum is like the "smallest" way to sum up the algebras.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both sums are usually considered, but the second one is often called the product. The direct sum is more natural, because if you embed each $\mathfrak A_n$ in its component, the direct sum is precisely the C$^*$-algebra generated by these embeddings.

The product is "unnatural" in the sense that if you take the product of countably many separable C$^*$-algebras you get a non-separable C$^*$-algebra. So the product makes more sense for von Neumann algebras than it does for C$^*$-algebras.